# Get package childs from a package

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

In Eclipse, how can I get the package's children?

Consider this example:

```
+ org.stack
    org.stack.test
        - StackTest.java
    - Stack.java
```

When we do IPackageFragment.getChildren() in *org.stack*, the Eclipse JDT only returns the compilation unit (Java Files)! But I want all children of a package: all ICompilationUnits and all Packages.

In this example when I apply IPackageFragment.getChildren() in *org.stack*, I want the *org.stack.test* and the ICompilationUnit *Stack.java*...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

IPackageFragment is not the correct starting point. You have to ask a higher level for the packages:

> IPackageFragment: A single package. It contains ICompilationUnits or IClassFiles, depending on whether the IPackageFragmentRoot is of type source or of type binary. **Note that IPackageFragment are not organized as parent-children. E.g. net.sf.a is not the parent of net.sf.a.b. They are two independent children of the same IPackageFragmentRoot.**

Have a look at this article about the [AST](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html)

Comment: I don't want to use AST to parse this information... So, I need to look to all of IPackageFragment names and check if the Package is or isn't child of other Package, right?

Comment: @zecapistolas: have you read the quote about IPackageFragmentRoot?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that should be close to what you needed.  (Since we're a bit past 2011, I doubt it will help you much, but maybe it will help somebody else.) Doubtless it can stand some improvement.

Since it doesn't seem possible to directly recurse downward from the `IPackageFragment` (as mentioned by Kai), the basic idea is to get the higher level `IPackageFragmentRoot` and filter it's children based on the original fragment's path.

```
PackageFragment originFragment; // = org.stack's fragment
try {
    String fragmentPath = originFragment.getPath().toString();
    IJavaElement parent = originFragment.getParent();
    ArrayList<IJavaElement> allChildren =
            new ArrayList<IJavaElement>();

    if (parent instanceof IPackageFragmentRoot) {
        IPackageFragmentRoot root = (IPackageFragmentRoot)parent;
        IJavaElement[] rootChildren = root.getChildren();

        // originsFragments includes the origin and all package
        // fragments beneath it
        List<IJavaElement> originsFragments =
           Arrays.asList(rootChildren).stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getPath().toString().startsWith(fragmentPath))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        allChildren.addAll(originsFragments);

        // Gather the children of the package fragments
        for (IJavaElement o : originsFragments) {
            if (o instanceof IPackageFragment ) {
                IPackageFragment oFragment = (IPackageFragment)o;
                IJavaElement[] fChildren = oFragment.getChildren();
                allChildren.addAll(Arrays.asList(fChildren));
            }
        }
    }
} catch (JavaModelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

An alternative inelegant solution would be to start with the original fragment's path and then use Java's file and directory facilities to descend through the directory hierarchy.  Then, you can use `IJavaProject`'s [findPackageFragment](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIJavaProject.html)`(IPath path)` to connect to the proper `IPackageFragments`.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do it in a recursive way.

here's some pseudo code

```
findAllClasses(package, classesCollection) {
    for(Class c: package.getClasses)
        classesCollection.add(c.getResourcePath)
    if(package.hasChildPackages)
        for(Package p: packages)
            findAllClasses(p, classesCollection)
}
```

Comment: This answer uses Java reflection, not the JDT API.